# JQM table responsive

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
<table data-role="table" id="statement" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-body-d ui-shadow table-stripe ui-responsive" data-column-btn-theme="b" data-column-btn-text="Headings" data-column-popup-theme="a">
    <thead>
    <tr class="ui-bar-d">
    <th data-priority="1">Category</th>
    <th data-priority="5">Date</th>
    <th data-priority="1">Debit</th>
    <th data-priority="1">Credit</th>
    <th data-priority="1">Balance</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>

$.each(data, function(index, item) {
    $("#statement").append("<tr>"+
    "<td>" + item.category + "</td>"+
    "<td>" + item.transaction_date + "</td>"+
    "<td>" + item.debit + "</td>"+
    "<td>" + item.credit + "</td>"+
    "<td>" + item.Balance + "</td>"+
    "</tr>");
});
```

I am trying to incorporate the responsive feature of JQM so that on small screens the user can select the columns he wants to display and hide. The data is displayed nice and everything works, the problem i am facing is that when i try to select the column to hide, only the heading(th on thead) section disappears and no effect on table data inside tbody section.

I also noticed that if i don't populate the table dynamically with jquery, and decide to popualte the table by adding table rows with dummy data inside tbody. The effect of hiding affect both the thead as well as tbody section(column completely disappears), it works fine. So i think the problem is due to adding data dynamically.

Can anyone please help me sort this out

Comment: hey could you create a jsfiddle so we can debug it better? You could try to refresh the table after adding data like so: $( "#statement" ).table( "refresh" );

Comment: Thank you @TheWandererr. The effect now shows on both the thead and tbody. But the next problem is that the wrong column disappears. It hides the next column instead of the current selected one. At least something came out. Thank you. E.g if i have the following columns (Surname,name,Age), then i decide to hide Surname, it instead hides name, if i decide to hide name, it hides Age, and if i decide to hide Age, it hides Surname. What coul be the problem with this? Sorry i have not used jsfiddle before

Comment: how are you hiding the columns?

Comment: The responsive JQM table has a heading button on top of the table that upon clicking it, will pop up the the list of columns heading-names of that particular table. And every name has a corresponding checkbox besides it, that when checked will automatically hide the column name selected. I think its a feature that JQM has. We don't program it. My code after i edited it as you suggested, it does hides columns, but it hides the wrong column.

Comment: mhh strange it is working for me. NOTE: You should add the content inside the tbody and not inside the table as you are doing right now. So you should change that from $("#statement").append(...)  to $("#statement tbody").append(...)

Comment: i did edit it, i changed it to instead. $('#statement > tbody').append(), but it still hides the wrong column. Thanx for your contribution. Will also try to diagnose the problem.